# Prove $S^1$ is not homeomorphic to $S^2$ using connectedness

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity, connectedness

I have to prove that the unit circle $S^1$ is not homeomorphic to the sphere $S^2$ using connectedness. Intuitively I know this is true, but I'm not sure how to prove this.. Can someone help me?

Comment: 1) Is "$S^1$ minus two different points" connected ? 2) Is "$S^2$ minus two different points" connected ? 3) If $S^1$ were homeomorphic to $S^2$ the answers to questions 1) and 2) would be identical.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought I could only answer the question with removing one point, but ofcourse 2 points removing is also allowed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $f:S^1\to S^2$ is a homeomorphism, and $a,b\in S^1$, with $a\ne b$.

Then 
$$f: S^1\setminus\{a,b\}\to S^2 \setminus\{\,f(a),f(b)\},$$
would also be a homeomorphism.

However, $S^1\setminus\{a,b\}$ is not connected, while $S^2 \setminus\{\,f(a),f(b)\}$ is connected.

Comment: Could you explain why $S^1\setminus\{a,b\}$ is not connected, $S^2\setminus\{f(a),f(b)\}$ is connected?