# Are the spaces $S^1$ and $S^2$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Is the following statement is true/false ?

Is the spaces $S^1$ and $S^2$  with  their topology inherited from $ \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ respectively are homeomorphics ?

My thinking  : yes , I think  both are homeomorphics  because both $\mathbb{R}^2 - \{0\} $ and $\mathbb{R}^3-\{0\}$ are connected

Comment: $S^2$ is *simply connected*, $S^1$ isn't.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  $S^1 $ is circle  so it is both compact and connected

Comment: $S^1$ is compact, connected but not simply connected.

Comment: why u used simply word  ?

Comment: "u"? Anyway see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown thanks u  i got its

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove $S^1$ is not homeomorphic to $S^2$ using connectedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610664/prove-s1-is-not-homeomorphic-to-s2-using-connectedness). Search the site before posting, please.

Comment: $\dim(S^2) = 2 \neq 1 = \dim(S^1)$ so they're not homeomorphic as topological dimension is a topological invariant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not - $S^2$ has trivial fundamental group, i.e. it is simply connected, while $S^1$ isn‘t.

Alternatively you can see that by noticing that $S^2$ minus two points is connected while $S^1$ minus two points isn‘t.

Comment: Morphisms between spaces can be called "null-homotopic" but not spaces themselves. Do you mean that the fundamental group of $S^2$ is trivial?

Comment: @desiigner Thank you. Yes, that‘s what I meant.