# Proving $S^2$ minus $2$ points are connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Prove $S^1, S^2$ are not homeomorphic.

Assume there is a homeomorphism $f: S^1\to S^2.$
I have proved that if we remove a point $p$ in $S^1$, $S^1\setminus\{p\}$ is connected.
I wonder if we remove a point $p$ in $S^2$, is $S^2\setminus\{p\}$ is connected? 
Moreover, I found this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610664/prove-s1-is-not-homeomorphic-to-s2-using-connectedness?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I don't understand if we remove $2$ disctinct points $a,b$ in $S^2$, then $S^2\setminus\{a,b\}$ is connected? (I understood $S^1\setminus\{a,b\}$ is not connected.)
I also found this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3321644/are-the-spaces-s1-and-s2-homeomorphic), but it doesn't answer my question.
Could someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can someone prove $S^2$ minus $2$ points are connected?

Comment: Try to prove that $S^2$ minus 2 points is homeomorphic to $ R^2$ minus 1 point. I think the stereographic projection could help

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$S^1$ minus a point is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

$S^2$ minus a point is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I can prove $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^2$ are not homeomorphic, but could you show me how $S^1$ (rsp $ S^2)$ minus a point is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (rsp $\mathbb{R}^2$)?

Comment: @AlexNguyen, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be $S^2$ minus $2$ distinct points. Roughly speaking, you can "move" the missing points to diametrically opposite positions on the sphere and "stretch" them to find that $C \sim S^1 \times (0, 1)$. Both $S^1$ and $(0, 1)$ are connected. So must be their product.